# Simple example using BernoulliNB (naive bayes classifier) scikit-learn in python - cannot explain classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, scikit-learn

Using scikit-learn 0.10

Why does the following trivial code snippet:

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import *

import sklearn
from sklearn.naive_bayes import *

print sklearn.__version__

X = np.array([ [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
               [0, 0, 0, 0, 0] ])
print "X: ", X
Y = np.array([ 1, 2 ])
print "Y: ", Y

clf = BernoulliNB()
clf.fit(X, Y)
print "Prediction:", clf.predict( [0, 0, 0, 0, 0] )
```

Print out an answer of "1" ?  Having trained the model on [0,0,0,0,0] => 2 I was expecting "2" as the answer.

And why does replacing Y with

```
Y = np.array([ 3, 2 ])
```

Give a different class "2" as an answer (the correct one) ?  Isn't this just a class label?

Can someone shed some light on this?

Comment: You are right, changing Y shouldn't change anything. I could reproduce with the current master. I guess this has to do with the classifier being undecided.

Comment: Using 0.18.2, I'm getting 2 without changing alpha.

Answer (score 8):

By default, alpha, the smoothing parameter is one. As msw said, your training set is very small. Due to the smoothing, no information is left. If you set alpha to a very small value, you should see the result you expected.

Answer (score 5):

Your training set is too small as can be shown by

```
clf.predict_proba(X)
```

which yields

```
array([[ 0.5,  0.5],
       [ 0.5,  0.5]])
```

which shows that the classifier views all classifications as equiprobable. Compare with the sample shown in the documentation for [BernoulliNB](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.BernoulliNB.html#sklearn.naive_bayes.BernoulliNB) for which `predict_proba()` yields:

```
array([[ 2.71828146,  1.00000008,  1.00000004,  1.00000002,  1.        ],
       [ 1.00000006,  2.7182802 ,  1.00000004,  1.00000042,  1.00000007],
       [ 1.00000003,  1.00000005,  2.71828149,  1.        ,  1.00000003],
       [ 1.00000371,  1.00000794,  1.00000008,  2.71824811,  1.00000068],
       [ 1.00000007,  1.0000028 ,  1.00000149,  2.71822455,  1.00001671],
       [ 1.        ,  1.00000007,  1.00000003,  1.00000027,  2.71828083]])
```

where I applied `numpy.exp()` to results to make them more readable. Obviously, the probabilities are not even close to equal and in fact well classify the training set.